# Sample points from each feature in a featurecollection (Google Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, vector-grid, sample

I created a grid (featurecollection containing various rectangular features) by coveringGrid function, and now I want to sample 10 points within a feature, and for every feature in this featurecollection.

```
var grid = geometry1.coveringGrid('EPSG:4326', 500000); 
// 'geometry1': a polygon that I draw
```

This code for the first feature works :

```
var list = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
    region:grid.geometry().geometries().get(0), points:10});
```

However, this code for all features does not work (It gave me an empty list of the same length of the featurecollection):

```
var list = ee.List.sequence({start:0, end:959, step:1});
list = list.map(function(n){
  return ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
    region:grid.geometry().geometries().get(n), points:10})
});
print(list);

// end:959 is the length of the featurecollection.
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your list is indexed from 0 so the end should be 958.

This works for me:

```
var grid = geometry.coveringGrid('EPSG:4326', 100000); 
print(grid.size())
var list = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
    region:grid.geometry().geometries().get(0), points:10});
print(list);
Map.addLayer(list, {}, 'list')
    
var list = ee.List.sequence({start:0, end:grid.size().subtract(1), step:1});
list = ee.FeatureCollection(list.map(function(n){
  return ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
    region:grid.geometry().geometries().get(n), points:10})
}));
print(list.flatten().size());
Map.addLayer(list.flatten(), {}, 'list')
```